# Getting Response Headers with node request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, request

I'm trying to retrieve the server response header for a request from a server.

```
import 'request' from 'request'

var url = "SOME_URL"

var options = { url: url };

var callback = function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error){
        console.log(response); // <==
    }
}

request(options, callback)
```

Going through the "response" object it doesn't look like it contains the ***Server response-header*** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_header_fields.htm

The only header being returned after doing this

```
console.log(response.headers)
```

is from the client request header.

Can anyone point in towards the right direction in order to access this object.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 7):

use

`response.headers`

instead of

`response.header`